# Test Redux-Saga 'yield call'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to write a unit test to the following saga :

```js
function * verifyCode(api){
    let action =  yield take(LoginTypes.VERIFY_CODE)
    const phoneNumber = yield select(phoneNumberSelector)
    try{
      const response = yield call(api.verifyCode, phoneNumber, action.code)
      if (response.ok){
        let token = response.data.token
        yield put(LoginActions.verifyCodeSuccess(response.data.token))
      }
      else {
        yield put(LoginActions.verifyCodeFailure(response.error))
      }
    }
    catch(error){
      yield put(LoginActions.verifyCodeFailure(error))
    }
}
```

All the tests pass up until the 'yield call' part, using the following (using test from 'tape'):

```js
test('verify code flow', (assert) => {
  let number = '0000000'
  let code = '00000'
  const gen = verifyCode(api)


  assert.deepEqual(
      gen.next({code: code}).value,
      take(LoginTypes.VERIFY_CODE),
      'wait for verify code action from user',
  )

  assert.deepEqual(
    gen.next().value,
    select(phoneNumberSelector),
    'get phoneNumber from login state'
  )
    assert.deepEqual(
      gen.next().value,
      call(api.verifyCode, number, code),
      'call verify code'
    )
  assert.end()
})
```

The error I get for the failure of this test is

```
   operator: deepEqual
expected: |-
  { '@@redux-saga/IO': true, CALL: { context: null, fn: [Function: verifyCode], args: [ '0000000', '00000' ] } }
actual: |-
  { '@@redux-saga/IO': true, PUT: { channel: null, action: { type: 'VERIFY_CODE_FAILURE', error: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined] } } }
```

1. What is the correct way to write to an api call using the 'call' effect?
2. How can I test the different possible flows depending on the ''response I get?

Answer (score 0):

1. This is the correct way to use the call effect on an API
2. To test different flows (Success | Failure) you can use the following pattern (in Jest):

> ```
> expect(generator.next().value.PUT.action).toMatchObject({type: types.VERIFY_CODE_SUCCESS, payload: {}, meta: { section }});
>
> expect(generator.throw('error').value.PUT.action).toMatchObject({ type: VERIFY_CODE_FAILURE, payload: 'error'});
> ```

BTW: It seems that your test fails due to an error thrown when you called your API endpoint. Make sure you get the desired response from your endpoint.

Good Luck!